# Google Spreadsheet with a service account

Tags: java, google-api, google-sheets-api

I want to access a spreadsheet on Google Drive by using de java Google spreadsheet API. In the past i used the client login method to login but this method is deprecated now.
Now I'm trying to use a service account to getting authenticated without interaction with the user because the tool is running in the background i needs to be automated. But i can't get it working. These my code now.

```
    List<String> SCOPES_ARRAY = Arrays.asList(
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
            "https://docs.google.com/feeds",
            "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds");
    credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(transport)
                .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                .setServiceAccountId(
                        "xxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
                .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES_ARRAY)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(p12)
                .setServiceAccountUser("me@gmail.com")
                .build();
    service = new SpreadsheetService("MonitorV3");
    service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);

    SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");

    worksheetFeed = service.getFeed(spreadsheet.getWorksheetFeedUrl(),
                    WorksheetFeed.class);
```

But i'm getting a nullpointerexception when executing the last line. something goes wrong with refresh token. Is there someone seeing what i'm doing wrong?[image]

I made a standalone simple application and now I get following detailded error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Failed to refresh access token: 401 Unauthorized
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory$OAuth2Token.refreshToken(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:260)
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.handleSessionExpiredException(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:702)
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.handleSessionExpiredException(GoogleService.java:738)
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:649)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1017)
at JavaApplication20.printDocuments(JavaApplication20.java:50)
at main.main(main.java:35)
```

Comment: did you grant the service account access to the sheet?

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. how can you give a service account access to it? The user with the email in serviceaccountuser has access to the spreadsheet. I even tried with tho owner of the drive but same result. I think i do something wrong or forget something. When i debug the thread. i see that after getfeed it will go into the sessionExpiredException and after that in de refreshtoken method where the nullpointer appears. Do I need to set an refreshtoken or something?

Comment: take the service account email address and give it access like you would another user.

Comment: I tried this but same result: nullpointer. I edited my post and added an image of where the nullpointer happens exactly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this by using following code:

```
credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(transport)
            .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
            .setServiceAccountId("618982716759-9ele96d95b7gqar6tn2ofa7jrjrudlol@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(p12)
            .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES_ARRAY).build();
            credential.refreshToken();
```

So without the .setServiceAccountUser("me@gmail.com"). Now it's working without any errors.

Comment: When i try to access the sheet, it is asking me to request for access. How to provide permissions to users ?

Comment: @BiscuitCoder try sharing the sheet (from the google sheets UI) to the service account email address.

Answer (score 7):

`GoogleCredential` is currently deprecated. Instead, if you need to access Google Sheets using a service account, use the [Google OAuth2 library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java).

Usage example:

```java
// A few common declarations:
private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "My Google Sheets Application";
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS_READONLY);

// Initializing the service:
final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
GoogleCredentials googleCredentials;
try(InputStream inputSteam = <YOURCLASS>.class.getResourceAsStream("/path/to/credentials/file.json")) {
  googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(credentialsStream).createScoped(SCOPES)
}
Sheets service = Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, new HttpCredentialsAdapter(googleCredentials))
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build()
```

Comment: I'm confused. I'm using a IDE that supports Maven, but not Gradle, and I don't know how to connect my service account on google sheets with my code. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Another approach to access Google Sheets with Google Service account is:

```
InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("service_account_key.json"); // put your service account's key.json file in asset folder.

GoogleCredential googleCredential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(inputStream)
                  .createScoped(Collections.singleton(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS_READONLY));
```

Important points to note here that:

- You should write your block of code to access Google Sheets in a Thread or Async call.
- If you get any exception like android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork, then please include these lines before making Async call:

  `StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
          .permitAll().build();
   StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);`

Please refer below documentations for detailed explanation:

https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/android?hl=es-419#step_5_setup_the_sample
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests

Happy Androiding.

Comment: What is the code in getAssets()? Without it, it's a bit difficult to understand.

Comment: in Android, i guess it is just "context.getAssets()" if you are in a Fragment, or just "getAssets()" in a Activity