# Irritating Google API Client (Java) Issues

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-api-java-client

So what I'm doing requires that I hit a document with the google sheets api, grab a sheet, pull data from it, and generate another sheet. So initially I followed an example using a service account as follows:

```
@Bean(name = "google-creds")
@DependsOn(value = {"google-http-transport", "google-data-store", "json-factory"})
public GoogleCredential authorize(HttpTransport transport, JsonFactory factory) throws Exception {
    // Load client secrets.
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("config/oauth.json"));
    return GoogleCredential.fromStream(in, transport, factory).createScoped(SCOPES);
}
```

My oauth.json file is using the json files generated in the API console credentials tab. I generated a service account as instructed...I was a bit dubious.

I was able to pull data from the document I wanted, and I was able to create another document. However from what I can tell there is no possible way to view documents created with a service account. Which...I mean that makes it completely and utterly useless. If there is a way where I can view these documents from the master account the service account was created with that'd be fantastic. A few google answers seem to imply this is not possible however.

So alright I decided how about I try using a client ID from the master account. I download the json file provided and...it errors and says unknown field 'type'. So..I guess it serializing using the RuntimeTypeAdapter from gson or something. So it's completely incompatble with the credential format from the master account.

So next I tried to do this

```
    @Bean(name = "google-creds")
    @DependsOn(value = {"google-http-transport", "google-data-store"})
    public Credential authorize(HttpTransport transport) throws Exception {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("config/oauthnew.json"));
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), new InputStreamReader(in));
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(transport, factory, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new MemoryDataStoreFactory()).build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        return credential;
    }
```

So I hadn't really read into this, and it turns out it creates a local jetty server for...some inexplicable reason. It also asks me to go visit a URL which then bitches about redirects. I have no desire for any kind of redirection, or...anything outside of parsing and making a goddamned spreadsheet. Also visiting a URL is already a deal breaker if it requires the account to be authenticated already. This needs to run programmatically once every 10 minutes or so.

Further, when I used the upper example I couldn't find anywhere to configure sharing or permissions in any way shape or form. Google usually has good APIs, but this is the single most irritating API I've used in nearly a decade of Java development. I just need to be able to A) Parse sheet A B) Create sheet B if necessary and C) Be able to view sheet B

Can someone point me in a direction that doesn't have me screaming at my monitor?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31287911/

Comment: So, as a quick recap, the way you're doing it, makes the service account the owner of the newly created sheet. 
I'm not 100% sure what you mean by Master account though. Also, is G Suite involved here or are we talking about 'normal' Google Accounts?

Comment: @noogui Incorrect I've already done what that person is trying to do. My goal is entirely different. I even gave 3 requirements (A,B,C) to illustrate that fact.



EdoAkse I'm using a normal google account, and trying to view one spreadsheet on that account, and create another spreadsheet which is viewable. 

I have tried the oAuth2 method, but I have no idea how I'm going to authorize the application for my account on the server. So I either need accessible service acct docs or oAuth headless.

Comment: So, in that case I see 2 options. One would be to create the sheet with the service account, and programatically grant access to the sheet to the user account. Drawback is that the service account is going to be the owner of the sheet, with all it's implications. You can [transfer ownership](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-sharing) afterwards though.

Comment: Another would be to do the OAuth2 flow where you grant access to sheets to your webapp once and store the credentials created. Then you can create files that are owned by the user account by using the stored credentials. This means that first you have to do the OAuth2 flow to get the credentials, save these somewhere, and then use the stored credentials for further actions (such as the creation of new sheets). There's a library available for Java, and the whole process is explained [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2) from start to finish.

Comment: Thanks Edo! Also sorry for the late resposne. So I did the service account thing with ownership transfer and it worked great. The oauth 2 flow seemed to work at first, but it was asking me to re-authorize the application basically every time I started it up which was pretty not-okay.
The service account seems to have no similar problems, and it's been running for like a week straight. No idea how to accept an answer, but much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Service account is used to access user date programatically and it hasn't got its own documents / drive. You need to provide the email address of a user while creating GoogleCredential. Than the service account will access that user document required (Granted that it has Domain wide delegation enabled). There is currently an open issue with the GoogleCredentials fromStream, please have a look at  (work around it) https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client/issues/1007#issuecomment-318493967

If the user account is a gsuite account you can give the service account permission to the scopes through the Google Admin console https://admin.google.com/

For details on domain wide delegation and granting access, please have a look at https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation

In order to view a document that was created by Service account with domain wide delegation you will have to access it with the user account.

Now in case of an account that you can grant access to with Google admin console, you will have to use the flow (your second approach). This will unfortunately require that you will have to grant permission to the documents through the url provided. You could store the tokens once the permission is granted, that way there would be no need to repeat this process.